Explainability using SHAP (for binary classification)
This is what I did:
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import shap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the dataset
thyroid_disease_data = pd.read_csv ("./Thyroid_Diff.csv")


# Encode categorical features
categorical_features = ['Gender', 'Smoking', 'Hx Smoking', 'Hx Radiothreapy',
                        'Thyroid Function', 'Physical Examination', 'Adenopathy', 'Pathology',
                        'Focality', 'Risk', 'T', 'N', 'M', 'Stage', 'Response', 'Recurred']

for col in categorical_features:
    thyroid_disease_data[col] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(thyroid_disease_data[col])

# Define inputs and target
x = thyroid_disease_data.drop(columns=['Recurred'])  # inputs
y = thyroid_disease_data['Recurred']                 # target

# Split the data
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Train models
logistic_reg = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000).fit(x_train, y_train)
decision_tree_clf = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(x_train, y_train)
random_forest_clf = RandomForestClassifier().fit(x_train, y_train)

# Initialize SHAP explainers
explainer_logistic_reg = shap.Explainer(logistic_reg, x_train)
explainer_decision_tree = shap.Explainer(decision_tree_clf, x_train)
explainer_random_forest = shap.Explainer(random_forest_clf, x_train)

# Compute SHAP values
shap_values_logistic_reg = explainer_logistic_reg(x_test)
shap_values_decision_tree = explainer_decision_tree(x_test)
shap_values_random_forest = explainer_random_forest(x_test)

# Ensure SHAP values and features have consistent shapes
shap_values_decision_tree_array = shap_values_decision_tree.values
shap_values_random_forest_array = shap_values_random_forest.values

# Visualize Feature Importance
shap.initjs()

# Summary plot for Logistic Regression
shap.summary_plot(shap_values_logistic_reg, x_test, plot_type="bar", feature_names=x.columns.tolist())
plt.show()

# Summary plot for Decision Tree
shap.summary_plot(shap_values_decision_tree_array, x_test, plot_type="bar", feature_names=x.columns.tolist())
plt.show()

# Summary plot for Random Forest
shap.summary_plot(shap_values_random_forest_array, x_test, plot_type="bar", feature_names=x.columns.tolist())
plt.show()

# Force plot for the first instance in the test set for each model
shap.force_plot(explainer_logistic_reg.expected_value, shap_values_logistic_reg.values[0], x_test.iloc[0], matplotlib=True)
plt.show()

shap.force_plot(explainer_decision_tree.expected_value, shap_values_decision_tree_array[0], x_test.iloc[0], matplotlib=True)
plt.show()

shap.force_plot(explainer_random_forest.expected_value, shap_values_random_forest_array[0], x_test.iloc[0], matplotlib=True)
plt.show()

# Dependence plot for a specific feature (e.g., 'Age' if it exists in your dataset)
if 'Age' in x.columns:
    shap.dependence_plot("Age", shap_values_logistic_reg.values, x_test, feature_names=x.columns.tolist())
    plt.show()
    shap.dependence_plot("Age", shap_values_decision_tree_array, x_test, feature_names=x.columns.tolist())
    plt.show()
    shap.dependence_plot("Age", shap_values_random_forest_array, x_test, feature_names=x.columns.tolist())
    plt.show()

But it says there is an error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 56
     53 plt.show()
     55 # Summary plot for Decision Tree
---> 56 shap.summary_plot(shap_values_decision_tree_array, x_test, plot_type="bar", feature_names=x.columns.tolist())
     57 plt.show()
     59 # Summary plot for Random Forest

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/shap/plots/_beeswarm.py:595, in summary_legacy(shap_values, features, feature_names, max_display, plot_type, color, axis_color, title, alpha, show, sort, color_bar, plot_size, layered_violin_max_num_bins, class_names, class_inds, color_bar_label, cmap, show_values_in_legend, use_log_scale)
    591 proj_shap_values = shap_values[:, sort_inds[0], sort_inds]
    592 proj_shap_values[:, 1:] *= 2  # because off diag effects are split in half
    593 summary_legacy(
    594     proj_shap_values, features[:, sort_inds] if features is not None else None,
--> 595     feature_names=feature_names[sort_inds],
    596     sort=False, show=False, color_bar=False,
    597     plot_size=None,
    598     max_display=max_display
    599 )
    600 pl.xlim((slow, shigh))
    601 pl.xlabel("")

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index


Try passing shap_values_decision_tree instead of shap_values_decision_tree_array to like this:
# Summary plot for Decision Tree
shap.summary_plot(shap_values_decision_tree, x_test, plot_type="bar", feature_names=x.columns.tolist())
plt.show()

